# Is it possible to overwrite variable name with suggestion by GCC automatically?

Tags: gcc

**WARNING**: without a well defined context, boundaries and adequate manual oversight, what is attempted here is a recipe for disaster!

In a project I need to rename a large number of class member variables. I started by renaming the declarations, so (as expected) I get a zillion errors such as:

```
error: ‘myvar’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘m_myvar’?
```

I know that it is possible to refactor this with some IDE-s;

What I am interested in is: since GCC already has mostly correct suggestions, is it possible to overwrite the variable names inside the code based on them?

Either by GCC itself or an external tool, or a script?

Comment: The suggestion is meant for humans, not for scripts, so don't try to feed it to a script. The results could be disastrous. Use an IDE.

Comment: I agree that without a well defined context, boundaries and adequate manual oversight, this is a disaster-recipe. Instead the topic of the questions is that is there any already available tooling to do this? I know the risks, and so should anyone who uses anything like this. I'll also add this warning to the question.